# cakephp 2.4 replace textarea with editable div

Tags: jquery, syntax-highlighting, contenteditable, cakephp-2.3

I am new to CakePHP. I have simple posts table, I want to add a syntax highlighter to `actions('add','edit')`

**add.ctp code:**

```
<h2>Create a Post</h2>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Post',array('noValidate'));
    echo $this->Form->input('title');

    //echo $this->Form->input('content');

    echo '<div class="input textarea">';
    echo '<label for="PostContent">Content</label>';
    echo '<div  onClick="this.contentEditable=\'true\';" style="border:1px solid #666;" id="PostContent" name="data[Post][content]" >&nbsp;</div>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo $this->Form->end('Save');
?>
```

I will dynamically append `pre` tag to this editable `div` as highlighter, but how do I replace `textarea(content)` with `div`? Currently on adding post it only inserts title but not the content.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the content of the div at the same time as the form, you can use a textarea like this :

```
$this->Form->textarea('content');
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#form-element-specific-methods

But at page init you hide it and only show the div.
Then with javascript you fill the textarea with the content of your div before the onsubmit event.